# ADE20K dataset - Extract class data from image segmentation maps

Tags: python, image, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to ***extract*** tag data from **image segmentation maps**, specifically **class data** from ADE20K dataset. I have attached an **example set of images** for context.

> I am also provided with a list of all object classes and their **RGB
> values** as shown

[image: RGB values]

[image: Segmentation map]

[image: Original Image]

[image: Folder struct- seg]

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly is needed? You want to relate masks with classes?

Comment: Each row has the color values for different segmented objects, I want to extract the class(e.g. Pillar, window, chair) data in each image using these values. The data is from the ADE20K dataset